# How to transform the context of fragment into a LifecycleOwner?

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-livedata

I have the following scenario. I have an activity which holds a fragment. In this fragment I'm displaying some records from a back-end database. I'm also using an adapter that looks like this:

```
public class MovieAdapter extends PagedListAdapter<Movie, MovieAdapter.MovieViewHolder> {
    private Context context;

    public MovieAdapter(Context context) {this.context = context;}

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MovieViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //Create the view
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MovieViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Movie movie = getItem(position);
        String title = movie.title;
        holder.titleTextView.setText(title);

        MovieRepository movieRepository = new MovieRepository(context);
        LiveData<Movie> liveData = movieRepository.retrieveFavoriteMovie(movie.id);
        liveData.observe(context, m -> { //Error
            if(m != null) {
                boolean favorite = m.favorite;
                if(favorite) {
                    //Do something
                } else {
                    //Do something else
                }
            }
        });
    }

    class MovieViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView favoriteImageView;
        TextView titleTextView;

        MovieViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            titleTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_text_view);                favoriteImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.favorite_image_view);
        }
    }
}
```

In the `onBindViewHolder` I'm trying to check if a specific movie exist in Romm database but I get this error:

```
Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'android.content.Context', required: 'android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner'
```

So how to transform the context of fragment into a `LifecycleOwner` so I can use it as in argument in my method?

Comment: Does your `Activity`  implements `LifecycleOwner` ? Also how are you passing `Context` to Adapter ?

Comment: You can use `context` as **`((Fragment) context)`** if **context** is instance of `Fragment`.

Comment: @ADM No, it does not. I'm passing the context to the constructor `public MovieAdapter(Context context) {this.context = context;}`. Do you have any idea how I can solve this? Thanks anyway!

Comment: @JeelVankhede I get `Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.content.Context' to 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment'`.

Comment: @ADM And being a fragment I'm using this `adapter = new MovieAdapter(getContext());` Is this correct?

Comment: Why do you need to observe LiveData inside Adapter? You are already receiving a `Movie`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I'm receiving a `Movie` from a backend server and I need to observe if a property (favorite) from my local database holds a specific value. How can I achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: You already have a `Movie` object, if you are using LiveData<PagedList then this should work without any additional observing.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I have a Movie object that I want to compare with a Movie object that exist within my Room database. Is this possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`android.content.Context` does not implement `android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner`.

You'd have to pass an instance of `AppCompatActivity`, which implements `android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner` (or any other class which does that).

or cast `(AppCompatActivity) context`, when `context` is an `instanceof`  `AppCompatActivity`. To get the Activity from the Context in a reliable manner, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/46205896/2413303

Comment: Thanks Martin, I'll try that.

Comment: I'm trying to pass to the constructor a new instance of the Fragment where I'm constructing the adapter but nothing happens. Do have any other idea? Thanks!

Comment: A simple cast to `AppCompatActivity` finally did the trick but it seems that in this case the observer is not removed :( I'll check that out and ask another question.

Comment: @IoanaP. there's also `.observeForever(Observer)` and `.removeObserver(Observer)` if there is demand for manually controlling the removal of the observation. see https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

Answer (score 1):

Posting this for people figuring out the solution suggested above, below i have added a short hand extension version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46205896/2413303) for kotlin android

```
private fun Context?.getLifeCycleOwner() : AppCompatActivity? = when {
    this is ContextWrapper -> if (this is AppCompatActivity) this else this.baseContext.getLifeCycleOwner()
    else -> null
}
```

#### Usage of above extension in a fragment would look like :

```
private var mainActivityContext: Context? = null //class level variable

//below statement called after context variable assigned / OnCreate
mainActivityContext?.getLifeCycleOwner()?.let { lifeCycleOwner ->
            YourViewModel.liveDataReturningMethod(text.toString())
                .observe(lifeCycleOwner , Observer { x ->
                    //your logic here...
                })
        }
```